# Error con consultas SQL - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tengo unos errores al momento de hacer unas consultas, y es que muestro como resultado areas con sus usuarios y con sus tipos. Esto lo hago con `join`, `group by` y `count`. El primer problema que tengo es que al momento de hacer la consulta me muestra el siguiente error:

codigo:

```
SELECT 
au.IdArea AS IdAreaUnidad,
au.Nombre AS AreaUnidad,
COUNT(dm.IdUsuario) AS TotalUsuarios,
/*CASE WHEN de.Etapa = 4 THEN COUNT(dm.IdUsuario) END AS TotalConcluidos,*/
CASE WHEN t.IdTipoSilencio = 1 THEN COUNT(t.IdTipoSilencio) END AS Automatico,
CASE WHEN t.IdTipoSilencio = 2 THEN COUNT(t.IdTipoSilencio) END AS SilencioPositivo,
CASE WHEN t.IdTipoSilencio = 3 THEN COUNT(t.IdTipoSilencio) END AS SilencioNegativo
FROM Usuarios d
JOIN Usuarios_Ejemplares de ON d.IdUsuario = de.IdUsuario
JOIN Tup t ON d.IdTup = t.IdTup
LEFT JOIN TipoSilencio ts ON t.IdTipoSilencio = ts.IdTipoSilencio
LEFT JOIN Area_Unidad au ON t.IdAreaUnidad = au.IdArea
LEFT JOIN Usuarios_Movimientos dm ON d.IdUsuario = dm.IdUsuario
GROUP BY  au.IdArea, au.Nombre, t.IdTipoSilencio/*, de.Etapa*/
```

resultado:

```
IdAreaUnidad    AreaUnidad          TotalUsuarios   Automatico  SilencioPositivo    SilencioNegativo
19              Hospital            1               1           NULL                NULL
6               Tesoreria           1               NULL        1                   NULL
8               Artesanía           1               NULL        1                   NULL
5               RR.HH               3               NULL        NULL                3
18              Transporte          6               NULL        NULL                6
19              Hospital            1               NULL        NULL                1
```

Como se puede ver en el resultado donde el `IdAreaUnidad` es 19, se repite 2 veces y es porque ambos tienen diferentes tipos uno tiene `automatico` y el otro `silencioNegativo`. Entonces tampoco se pueden sumar en la columna `TotalUsuarios`.
Y cuando quito la parte del codigo que esta con comentario se repite aun mas.

resultado del codigo sin comentarios:

```
IdAreaUnidad    AreaUnidad          TotalUsuarios   TotalConcluidos Automatico  SilencioPositivo    SilencioNegativo        
5               RR.HH               1               NULL            NULL        NULL                1               
5               RR.HH               2               NULL            NULL        NULL                2               
6               Tesoreria           1               NULL            NULL        1                   NULL            
8               Artesanía           1               NULL            NULL        1                   NULL            
18              Transporte          1               NULL            NULL        NULL                1               
18              Transporte          2               NULL            NULL        NULL                2               
18              Transporte          3               3               NULL        NULL                3               
19              Hospital            1               NULL            1           NULL                NULL            
19              Hospital            1               NULL            NULL        NULL                1
```

Necesito que se muestre todo sin repeticiones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes IdTipoSilencio en el `GROUP BY`. Pero viene de más atrás, porque seguramente te marcó que necesitabas agregarlo porque no era parte de una función de agregado. Por ello es que necesitas incluir todo el `CASE` en la función `COUNT()`.

```
SELECT 
    au.IdArea AS IdAreaUnidad,
    au.Nombre AS AreaUnidad,
    COUNT(dm.IdUsuario) AS TotalUsuarios,
    /*COUNT(CASE WHEN de.Etapa = 4 THEN dm.IdUsuario END) AS TotalConcluidos,*/
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.IdTipoSilencio = 1 THEN t.IdTipoSilencio END) AS Automatico,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.IdTipoSilencio = 2 THEN t.IdTipoSilencio END) AS SilencioPositivo,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN t.IdTipoSilencio = 3 THEN t.IdTipoSilencio END) AS SilencioNegativo
FROM Usuarios d
JOIN Usuarios_Ejemplares de ON d.IdUsuario = de.IdUsuario
JOIN Tup t ON d.IdTup = t.IdTup
LEFT JOIN TipoSilencio ts ON t.IdTipoSilencio = ts.IdTipoSilencio
LEFT JOIN Area_Unidad au ON t.IdAreaUnidad = au.IdArea
LEFT JOIN Usuarios_Movimientos dm ON d.IdUsuario = dm.IdUsuario
GROUP BY  au.IdArea, au.Nombre--, t.IdTipoSilencio/*, de.Etapa*/
```

Comment: gracias por el apoyo!